# How to get elasticsearch most used words?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using terms aggregation on elasticsearch to get most used words in a index with 380607390 (380 millions) and i receive timeout on my application.

The aggregated field is a text with a simple analyzer( the field holds post content).

My question is:

The terms aggregation is the correct aggregation to do that? With a large content field?

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "keywords" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "post_content" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using `min_doc_count`. You would ofcourse not want to get those words which have been used just once or twice or thrice...
You can set `min_doc_count` as per your requirement. This would definitely
reduce the time.

```
{
   "aggs" : {
    "keywords" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "post_content",
              "min_doc_count": 5               //----->Set it as per your need
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i try it now with min_doc_count set to 100, but not work to! also filter the query to a subset of documents to reduce the job, something is wrong, i now that , but what?

Comment: Are you getting `timeout` again?

Comment: Yes, i have two envs, the same search/aggs over one env works fine!

Comment: EnvA has less number of documents than Env B. And it working fine for Env B.?

Comment: Isn't that strange? Its working fine for large number of documents and not for less number of documents